# ADB Equivalent for iOS debugging?

Tags: ios, debugging, service, usb, adb

I want to jailbreak my iPhone but keep security. One of the ways that an Android passcode lock can be compromised, is via ADB running. Is there a similar service running on iPhone that I can disable in order to maintain security?